# How to overcome CoreAnimation warning while Implementing the Wikitude API in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calayer

I am using the Wikitude API in my iPhone app.
But while running the application i am getting the following warning and on coming of this warning i am not able to touch any POIs on the screen.
The warning is "CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]"
Please suggest me something to overcome this warning.

I am using the following code

```
wikitudeAR = [[WikitudeARViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self applicationPackage:nil applicationKey:nil; applicationName:nil developerName:nil];     

- (void) verificationDidSucceed {
    id appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];    
    [window addSubview:[wikitudeAR start];
}

- (void) verificationDidFail {

}

- (void) didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation*) newLocation
                fromLocation: (CLLocation*) oldLocation {

}

-(void) APIFinishedLoading {   
    //arr is  current location data
    NSMutableArray *addPOIData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr  count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict= [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        WTPoi* poi = [[WTPoi alloc] initWithName:currentMapLocation.locationTitle AndLatitude:[[dict objectforKey:@"lat"]doubleValue]AndLongitude:[[dict        objectforKey:@"long"]doubleValue]];
        poi.icon = @"http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9931/parking.png";
        poi.shortDescription = @"Open Monday to Friday 6:30 to 7pm. Tariff plan range from £5";
        poi.thumbnail = @"http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9931/parking.png";
        [addPOIData addObject: poi];
        [poi release];
    }

    [[WikitudeARViewController sharedInstance] addPOIs: addPOIData];
    [addPOIData release];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i also have the following issue my one seems to happen  after i keep reinstalling the app on to my iphone testing device ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the new version of the Wikitude iPhone API which should fix the described issue. You can download it from http://www.wikitude.org/developers

Cheers, Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

i also have the following issue my one seems to happen  after i keep reinstalling the app on to my iphone testing device ...

try the following:

limit name about 25 characters
limit description to 250 characters
icon and thumbnail should be small 50x50 going over 60x60 caused the same error in my case....

example::

```
WTPoi* poi25 = [[WTPoi alloc] initWithName:@"Car park: amwell street" AndLatitude:51.52899377167962 AndLongitude:-0.11010333895683289]; 
poi25.icon = @"http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9931/parking.png";
poi25.shortDescription = @"Open Monday to Friday 6:30 to 7pm. Tariff plan range from £5";
poi25.thumbnail = @"http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/9931/parking.png";
```

Comment: does your happen to be jailbreaking! this error really weird mine only happens sometimes normal when it does happen i put it on air plane mode start the app again and it goes away!!