# Augmented reality in iphone using wikitude API

Tags: iphone

I am working on the Augmented reality app in iphone.
But while running the application i am getting the following warning and on coming of this warning i am not able to touch any of the screen. 
The warning is"CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan] "
Please suggest me regarding it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We're probably going to need some code, if we're going to help with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overcome CoreAnimation warning while Implementing the Wikitude API in iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158812/how-to-overcome-coreanimation-warning-while-implementing-the-wikitude-api-in-ipho)

Comment: Don't re-ask the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the new version of the Wikitude iPhone API which should fix the described issue. You can download it from http://www.wikitude.org/developers